# Converting script to allow to run as scheduled task

Tags: vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I wrote a VBScript a while back to make a task easier.  It works, however it wont run as a scheduled task since it requires a command window to interact with.  How would I change the script to allow it to run as a scheduled task?

```
dim filesys
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

WScript.Sleep 2000  
objShell.SendKeys"dsdbutil"  
WScript.Sleep 2000 
objShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")  
WScript.Sleep 2000 
objShell.SendKeys("activate instance wap")
WScript.Sleep 2000 
objShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 2000 
objShell.SendKeys("ifm")
WScript.Sleep 2000 
objShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 2000 
objShell.SendKeys("create full c:\adldsbackup")
WScript.Sleep 2000 
objShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 30000 
objShell.SendKeys("quit")
WScript.Sleep 2000 
objShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 2000 
objShell.SendKeys("quit")
WScript.Sleep 2000 
objShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 2000 


filesys.MoveFile "c:\adldsbackup\adamntds.dit", "\\vash\ibts_ts\Networking\Backups\ADLDS\adamntds_" & DatePart("m",Now()) & "_" & DatePart("d",Now()) & "_" & DatePart("YYYY",Now()) & ".dit"

objShell.SendKeys("exit")
WScript.Sleep 2000 
objShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
```

Comment: im having a hard time getting it to format right..  but formatting isnt relevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar, scheduling a vbs. The solution is simple!

Create a **batch file** to run the vbs file and schedule this batch file. I prefer to use cscript in the batch files:

`cscript.exe //nologo <ScriptNameWithFullPath>`

Comment: this doesnt work...  The issue is they way the script is written, it needs the command propmt to interact with

Comment: In the vbs, add [AppActivate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek(v=vs.84).aspx) calls with matching Title of the application just before you want the SendKeys to apply.